# how to create RelativeLayout, do some actions in it, and then remove it in Kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-relativelayout

assume I have this fragment

```
<android...ConstraintLayout
  ...>
<ScrollView .../>

<RelativeLayout
  android:id=“@+id/fixed”
  android:layout_width=“match_parent”
  android:layout_height=“match_parent” />
<cl/>
```

what I would like to do is:

first, I create the RelativeLayout programmatically in kotlin

then, add the attributes to it

then, add it to its proper parent

finally, remove it

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: add it to the viewgroup and remove it when required. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  val myLayout = RelativeLayout(context).apply {
      layoutParams = *YourParentsLayoutType*.LayoutParams(
        *YourParentsLayoutType*.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        *YourParentsLayoutType*.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

      parentLayout.addView(this)
  }

  /* ... */

  parentLayout.removeView(myLayout)
```

Replace *YourParentsLayoutType* with your parent's layout type, for example FrameLayout.

If it's ConstraintLayout, you might need to set its constraints also.